# How can I implement 'select all' button in Django?

Tags: django

I'd like to implement `select all` button (e.g select all and deleting) in `Django 1.9.7` but I can't find any post about it in Google Since, I'm not a non-native-english person, I'm not good at googling in correct english. Could anybody give me advices or keywords so that I can googling based on it?

Comment: Try this in google: `how to implement select all using django and jquery`

Comment: Hahahah. LOL. Funny answer @karthikr

Answer (score 0):

Well this depends on how you implemented your table with Django. Putting javascript/bootstrap/etc aside, there are some samples on how you can implement select all in javascript. Like [this](https://www.sanwebe.com/2014/01/how-to-select-all-deselect-checkboxes-jquery).

Deleting those items requires defining a form and processing it's data in the serverside and deleting your model items. This also depends on how you are passing data between your view and your model.